# Open any image through my app

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have image on my email and I have to open it through my application just like when I press on image it gives the action sheet. I want to show my app option on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the system which file types your appe handles: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

Comment: can tell me what type setting i have do on info plist

Answer (score 1):

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>PDF</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
```

this is for adding pdf file.
update the code appropriately and paste in into your .plist file.